# What Crossover Method should I use for crossing Postfix expressions in Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, postfix-notation, crossover

I'm building a project whose main objective is to find a given number (if possible, otherwise closest possible) using 6 given numbers and main operators (+, -, *, /). Idea is to randomly generate expressions, using the numbers given and the operators, in reverse polish (postfix) notation, because I found it the easiest to generate and compute later. Those expressions are Individuals in Population of my Genetic Algorithm. Those expressions have the form of an ArrayList of Strings in Java, where Strings are both the operators and operands (the numbers given).

The main question here is, what would be the best method to crossover these individuals (postfix expressions actually)? Right now I'm thinking about crossing expressions that are made out of all the six operands that are given (and 5 operators with them). Later I'll probably also cross the expressions that would be made out of less operands (5, 4, 3, 2 and also only 1), but I guess that I should figure this out first, as the most complex case (if you think it might be a better idea to start differently, I'm open to any suggestions). So, the thing is that every expression is made from all the operands given, and also the child expression should have all the operands included, too. I understand that this requires some sort of ordered crossover (often used in problems like TSP), and I read a lot about it (for example [here](http://www.rubicite.com/Tutorials/GeneticAlgorithms.aspx) where multiple methods are described), but I didn't quite figure out which one would be best in my case (I'm also aware that in Genetic Algorithms there is a lot of 'trial and error' process, but I'm talking about something else here).

What I'm saying is bothering me, are operators. If I had only a list of operands, then it wouldn't be a problem to cross 2 such lists, for example taking a random subarray of half elements from 1 parent, and fill the rest with remaining elements from parent 2 keeping the order like it was. But here, if I, say, take first half of an expression from first parent expression, I would definitely have to fill the child expression with remaining operands, but what should I do with operators? Take them from parent 2 like the remaining operands (but then I would have to watch out because in order to use an operator in postfix expression, I need to have at least 1 operand more, and checking that all the time might be time consuming, or not?), or maybe I could generate random operators for the rest of the child expression (but that wouldn't be a pure crossover then, would it)?

When talking about crossover, there is also mutation, but I guess I have that worked out. I can take an expression and perform a mutation where I'll just switch 2 operands, or take an expression and randomly change 1 or more operators. For that, I have some ideas, but the crossover is what really bothers me.

So, that pretty much sums my problem. Like I said, the main question is how to crossover, but if you have any other suggestions or questions about the program (maybe easier representation of expressions - other then list of strings - which may be easier/faster to crossover, maybe something I didn't mention here, it doesn't matter, maybe even a whole new approach to the problem?), I'd love to hear them. I didn't give any code here because I don't think it's needed to answer this question, but if you think it would help, I'll definitely edit in order to solve this. One more time, main question is to answer how to crossover, this specific part of the problem (idea or pseudocode expected, although the code itself would be great, too :D), but if you think that I need to change something more, or you know some other solutions to my whole problem, feel free to say.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that come to mind:

## Approach #1

Encode each genome as a fixed length expression where odd indices are numbers and even indices are the operators. For mutation, you could slightly change the numbers and/or change the operators.

Pros:

- Very simple to code

Cons:

- Would have to create an infix parser
- Fixed length expressions

## Approach #2

Encode each genome as a syntax tree. For instance, `4 + 3 / 2 - 1` is equivalent to `Add(4, Subtract(Divide(3, 2), 1))` which looks like:

```
   _____+_____
   |         |
   4     ____-____
         |       |
       __/__     1
       |   |
       3   2
```

Then when crossing over, pick a random node from each tree and swap them. For mutation, you could add, remove, and/or modify random nodes.

Pros:

- Might find better results
- Variable length expressions

Cons:

- Adds time complexity
- Adds programming complexity

Here is an example of the second approach:

[image: Crossover performed on trees]

[Source](http://www.gene-expression-programming.com/webpapers/Ferreira-ACS2002/section2/SS1.htm)

Comment: Thanks for concise answer, I like how you wrote pros and cons for both approaches. I understand what has been done in this example at the end, but the catch is that operands need to remain the same, so just swaping a part of an expression wouldn't be enough in most cases. Besides, I like this tree syntax, and I'll probably be thinking in that way from now on.

Comment: @Urke If I understand you correctly, you are given `6` numbers and can also use `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`, similar to [this](http://appcrawlr.com/ios/6-numbers-by-brainbow) game. So, if you decided to use the syntax tree method, all of the [operands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand) will be the leaves of the tree. Are you saying that the operators are fixed (in order) and you need to find the best permutation of the numbers?

Comment: @Ijeabmreosn Thanks again for your answer, I completely understand it. Right now I&#39;m hoping to hear another opinion, hopefully a new answer to this question, because I&#39;d like to think it all the way through before I get into it.